# Oracle MAF WebService invokeDataControlMethod SOAP error

Tags: web-services, mobile, soap, oracle-adf, oracle-maf

Any help in resolving this invokeDataControl Method will be greatly appreciated. Please find the link below for a complete reference of the problem. I was basically trying to execute an Oracle/Java MAF example to understand the concept and present it to user for a critical go/no-go situation.

Environment:

1) Jdeveloper 12.1.3.0.0 
2) MAF 2.0.1 
3) Example tried: DSI037 in https://java.net/projects/smuenchadf/pages/ADFMobile 
OR "http://deepakcs.blogspot.com/2013/06/offline-data-synchronization-for-adf.html"
4) MAC OS 10.9
5) WebLogic 12C
6) Error Message

[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - HttpServiceConnection - log] Connection Error: 500 
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - HttpTransport - parseResponse] Response [Error: {0}]: {1} 
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - SoapTransportLayer - invokeSoapRequest] Encountered exception while invoking SOAP request 
EndPoint: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80/EJBSyncWebServiceApp/SessionFacadeBeanService 
SOAPAction: "http://service.soap.dsid.com/persistDepartments" 
Exception: HTTP Status Code 500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

7) More Details:

The following code was executed. The method and all others are working fine in HTTP analyzer or when individually executed (binding "persistDepartments" with a button)  but not when wrapper in AdfmfJavaUtilities.invokeDataControlMethod

```
public void syncDataFromOfflineToOnline() {

      Trace.log(Utility.FrameworkLogger, Level.FINE, this.getClass(), "syncDataFromOfflineToOnline",
              "Executing syncDataFromOfflineToOnline Method");
    try {
        Connection conn = DBConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement pStmt =
            conn.prepareStatement("SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME, LOCATION_NAME, STATUS from DEPARTMENTS WHERE STATUS IN (?, ?, ?)");
        pStmt.setString(1, STATUS_NEWLY_CREATED);
        pStmt.setString(2, STATUS_MODIFIED);
        pStmt.setString(3, STATUS_DELETED);
        ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {

            List namesList = new ArrayList(1);
            List paramsList = new ArrayList(1);
            List typesList = new ArrayList(1);


            Departments dept = new Departments();
            dept.setDepartmentId(rs.getInt("DEPARTMENT_ID"));
            dept.setDepartmentName(rs.getString("DEPARTMENT_NAME"));
            dept.setLocationName(rs.getString("LOCATION_NAME"));
            dept.setStatus(STATUS_NOT_CHANGED);


            if (rs.getString("STATUS").equals(STATUS_NEWLY_CREATED)) {
                System.out.println("I got a STATUS_NEWLY_CREATED");
                GenericType gtDept =
                    GenericTypeBeanSerializationHelper.toGenericType("MYWS.Types.persistDepartments.arg0",
                                                                     dept);
                namesList.add("arg0");
                paramsList.add(gtDept);
                typesList.add(Object.class);

                AdfmfJavaUtilities.invokeDataControlMethod("MYWS", null, "persistDepartments", namesList,
                                                           paramsList, typesList);
                //Once the data sync with online, change the status for the row as STATUS_NOT_CHANGED

                PreparedStatement pStmt1 =
                    conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE DEPARTMENTS SET STATUS=? WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=?");
                pStmt1.setString(1, STATUS_NOT_CHANGED);
                pStmt1.setInt(2, rs.getInt("DEPARTMENT_ID"));
                pStmt1.execute();              
                conn.commit();

                <<< more codes >>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem.

Change the typesList.add(Object.class) to typesList.add(GenericType.class)

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the statement but still getiing the same error. It is working fine if I create a form ("arg0") with  a command button from "persistDepartments" DataControl object but I fail to understand why the same is not working when invoked programmatically through invokeDataControlMethod. To me the error messages also appear generic. So can somebdoy with web applications may help?

Comment: Changed but  getiing the same error. It is working fine if I add one record   using form ("arg0") but the same is not working when invoked programmatically through invokeDataControlMethod. To me the error messages also appear generic. So can somebody with web applications knowledge may help?     Error messge                   [SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - HttpServiceConnection - log] Connection Error: 500
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - HttpTransport - parseResponse] Response [Error: {0}]: {1}
[SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - SoapTransportLayer - invokeSoapRequest]